# Comparisons in merge-sort

Tags: sorting, runtime, mergesort

I have this homework problem asking for the asymptotic worst case of comparisons for merge-sort when sorting 0s and 1s.

This is confusing to me because it looks like merge-sort has the same number of comparisons for whatever is placed in it with n elements. I probably don't fully understand merge-sort. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case according to me would be when 0's and 1's would come alternatively and when the total number of elements is a factor of 4. This is because merging takes max time because of this. This way Merge sort has O(nlogn)